# Place JavaScript's variable into input type hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form can let user upload image and drag image's position where user like.

I use jQuery find out the position.

```
var top=parseFloat($("#preview_image").css('top'));
var left=parseFloat($("#preview_image").css('left'));

<form action='image.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='file'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Than I post the form in normal way, not use jQuery post. (because I have $_FILES[])

Here is the problem. How can I post `var top, .left` from JavaScript?

Is any way to put these 2 variable into input type hidden?

```
<input type='hidden' value='top'>
```

So I can post these 2 data to next page

Comment: Yes. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, just create the input elements, set their type to hidden, create name and value attributes and append them to the form. Should be a trivial task with jQuery.

Comment: You could just select the hidden input field(s) and set their values with jQuery before sending the form.

Comment: oh I didn't know jquery can do that lol, thx alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var top=parseFloat($("#preview_image").css('top'));
var left=parseFloat($("#preview_image").css('left'));

$('#preview_image_top').val(top);
$('#preview_image_left').val(left);

<form action='image.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='file'>
<input type='hidden' value='' name='preview_image_top' id='preview_image_top'>
<input type='hidden' value='' name='preview_image_left' id='preview_image_left'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').append(
  $('<input type="hidden" name="top"').val(top),
  $('<input type="hidden" name="left"').val(left)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the easiest way. Create the [`inputs`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.hidden.html#input.hidden), assign their respective values and names and append them to the [`form`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/form.html#form).

```
var top = parseFloat($('#preview_image').css('top')),
    left = parseFloat($('#preview_image').css('left'));

$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    value: top,
    name: 'top'
}).appendTo('form');

$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    value: left,
    name: 'left'
}).appendTo('form');
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this codes in your `document.ready` and it will work:

```
$('form').append($('<input type="hidden" name="top"').val(top),$('<input type="hidden" name="left"').val(left));
```